# developers.facebook.com issued access token VS OAuth generated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-permissions, facebook-access-token

Interesting problem I'm having right now.

Signing in an App gives a access token looking something like this:

```
AAACwFsGcSr4BAOGUTwfuZAWuUcwZC0rJ7noZCKMqhBI7ivDCsIGqduGIZCus5PRaS6KuREqxLmhfvZAZAkz5WCpFfANtUpYHgZD
```

This access token can't access users PUBLIC information, while one issued by Facebook on `developers.facebook.com` - CAN.

You can easily test this by logging to your facebook and going to this link: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

You'll see that Facebook automatically generates access token on DEMO urls like this one:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/music
    ?access_token=2227470867|2.AQCvlA_ZaJ2MfRR0.3600.1318266000.0-100001572415177|2FeweU6ZvOQS9OCF5ZBV58_PtPg
```

If you would change /ME/ to any user which has his MUSIC posted as public, you WILL be able to access that data with Graph API.

Now try to get an access token to your APP and call the same Graph API method with generated access token, the returned data is empty JSON object.

Whats’ the difference between these access tokens? How to obtain access token, that I could get public information using Graph API?

I was thinking that logging in your APP is the highest possible access token and the only higher token is token with specified permissions...

Any guidelines would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

I believe the difference is that you can specify additional permissions in a scope parameter,
so if you wanted to read a user's feed you would have to specify read_stream. I was trying to accomplish this with an access token from a server-side authentication flow in ruby, but the access token only allowed to me to navigate accross a certain portion of graph.facebook.com/user_id/feed? requests. If you get any insights or comes across a solution shoot it my way too, if you can.